# List of objects as numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a class with some fields, and I want it to be represented as numpy array.

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, cX, cY, rad, color):
        self.cX = cX
        self.cY = cY
        self.rad = rad
        self.color = color

    # some methods...
```

I know that in order to print I should define an `__str__()` method. Is there a similar mechanism for numpy arrays?
In particular, I want something like this:

```
list_of_objs = [Circle() for i in range(100)]
numpy_representatin = numpy.asarray(list_of_objs) # shape have to be (4, 100)
```

Thanks in advance!

UPD: forgot to mention, that all fields are assumed to be of the same type - int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following should help you: [Writing custom array containers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.dispatch.html)

As mentioned in the above link:

> "We can convert to a numpy array using `numpy.array` or `numpy.asarray`, which will call its `__array__`-method to obtain a standard `numpy.ndarray`."

Thus, your class could look something like

```py
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, cX, cY, rad, color):
        self.cX = cX
        self.cY = cY
        self.rad = rad
        self.color = color

    def __array__(self):
        return np.array([self.cX, self.cY, self.rad, self.color], np.int32)

    # some methods...
```